# How to frame basement window

Tags: basement, windows, window-frame

Good morning,

I'm working on finishing my basement and need some ideas on how to frame out around the windows to facilitate either a drywall or pine return. I'm using 1 inch xps on the walls and then studs flush against that.

How do I frame to give the drywall or pine returns something to attach to? There's a metal frame that creates the window opening and I don't think I can screw or nail into that.

I can put a stud flush against the edge of the opening and attach to it, but I'm worried the return won't be very stable where it extends to the window frame because I can't think of a way to support it closer to the window. [image: 3]

I'd appreciate any ideas.

Jay [[image: 12]

Answer (score 1):

Put your studs up to the edges of the window frame. Then attach your pine trim with finish nails into the studs and some dabs of adhesive caulk on the metal window frame.

Caulk the perimeter of the trim to the window.  That should make everything stable enough for normal use.

I prefer to use pvc trim in areas where condensation could be an issue. That is up to you.